# How to print a message to people who are not in the list

Tags: python

```
favourite_languages = {
    "jen": "python",
    "sarah": "c",
    "edward": "ruby",
    "phil": "python",
}

people = ["adam", "bavi", "phil"]

for name in favourite_languages.keys():
    print(name.title() + " thanks for doing the poll")
else:
    print(people[:] + " please do the poll")
```

I would like to alert people to do the poll if they are not in the dictionary and for people that are in the dictionary I will print "thank you".

Comment: The else clause will only be reached if there isn't a break called in the for loop, btw

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would already add the names into your dictionary and assign an empty string to the language. Then you can do the below:

```
favourite_languages = {
    "jen": "python",
    "sarah": "c",
    "edward": "ruby",
    "phil": "python",
}

people = ["adam", "bavi", "phil"]

for name in people: favourite_languages[name] = ''

for name, language in favourite_languages.items():
    print(name.title() + " thanks for doing the poll") if language else print(name + " please do the poll")
```

**EDIT**:
Update if duplicated names

```
for name in people: 
    if name not in favourite_languages:
        favourite_languages[name] = ''
    else:
        favourite_languages[name] = ['',favourite_languages[name]]

for name, language in favourite_languages.items():
    if isinstance(language,list):
        for language_dub in language: print(name.title() + " thanks for doing the poll") if language_dub else print(name + " please do the poll")
    else: print(name.title() + " thanks for doing the poll") if language else print(name + " please do the poll")
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Can I know what is the use of adding an empty string?

Comment: You could also you `None`, but since the idea is to store strings containing languages, I decided to go for an empty string. Also, python evaluates an empty string to `False`, hence in the `for loop` you can do `if language` and print `thanks for doing the poll` if `language` contains something, or `please do the poll` if the string is empty.
Although to be fair, python evaluates `None` also to `False`, so you could also use `None`.

Comment: This doesn't quite work: it overwrites `phil`'s language preference with an empty entry.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for name in list(set(list(favourite_languages.keys()) + people)): # Remove duplicates
    if name in favourite_languages.keys():
        print(f"{name.title()}, thanks for doing the poll")
    else:
        print(f"{name.title()}, please do the poll")
```

You need to check all the names that are there and iterate through that. Then, you can check if `name` is in `people`. If it is, then you can ask them to do the poll. Else, you thank them.

Comment: Thanks for helping. The output is phil will been asked to do the poll. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean `phil will been asked`?

Comment: phil will only asked to do the poll instead of thanking phil. If i would like to only thank him instead of asking him to do the poll, is there solution for this?

Comment: @Anscom Unfortunately, poor phil is located in both, the list and the dictionary. Was this on purpose or by accident?

Comment: I add it on purpose to test out if it's already in the dict, how can I exclude phil out.

Comment: @Anscom I have updated my answer to prioritize the dictionary instead of the list and to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
favourite_languages = {
    "jen": "python",
    "sarah": "c",
    "edward": "ruby",
    "phil": "python"
}

people = ["adam", "bavi", "phil"]

for name in people:
    if name in favourite_languages.keys():
        print(name + " thanks for doing the poll")
    else:
        print(name + " please do the poll")
```

Using this code, your output will yield

```
adam please do the poll
bavi please do the poll       
phil thanks for doing the poll
```

Comment: @12944qwerty yes it does

Comment: It's a partial answer. It doesn't thank the rest of the people in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

We can use a set to prevent repetition of the same value

```
req_set = {x for x in (list(favourite_languages) + people)}

for name in req_set:
    if name in favourite_languages:
        print(f"{name.title()}, thanks for doing the poll")
    else:
        print(f"{name.title()}, please do the poll")
```

Output:

```
Jen, thanks for doing the poll
Sarah, thanks for doing the poll
Edward, thanks for doing the poll
Adam, please do the poll
Bavi, please do the poll
Phil, thanks for doing the poll
```

if you want the names of those who havent done the poll at the end,

```
req_set = {x for x in (list(favourite_languages) + people)}

not_done = []
for name in req_set:
    if name in favourite_languages:
        print(f"{name.title()}, thanks for doing the poll")
    else:
        not_done.append(name)

print() # Prints an empty line to seperate the done and not done
for name in not_done:
    print(name.title(), end=", ")
print("please do the poll")
```

Output:

```
Sarah, thanks for doing the poll
Jen, thanks for doing the poll
Edward, thanks for doing the poll
Phil, thanks for doing the poll

Adam, Bavi, please do the poll
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two lists, with one message for each list.  Just use two loops:

```
for name in favourite_languages.keys():
    print(name + " thanks for doing the poll")

for name in people:
    print(name + " please do the poll")
```

Output:

```
jen thanks for doing the poll
sarah thanks for doing the poll
edward thanks for doing the poll
phil thanks for doing the poll
adam please do the poll
bavi please do the poll
phil please do the poll
```

Comment: The names in people are not in favourite languages

Comment: Thanks; I burned that answer to the ground and did an appropriate one.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code and it works only to the person in people. If I would like to thanks those in my dictionary. How can I do that. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it *does* iterate through the dict.  Please explain where it doesn't work for you.

Comment: If you noticed the last name in my dict is phil and the output with this code is giving phil please do the poll

Comment: @Anscom Because phil is also in people. It is in both

Comment: I would like to say only thank you to phil and not asking phil to do the poll again. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is; I amended my code.  Now it removes anyone in `favourite_languages.keys()` from the second loop.